# How to add Transition to width in span

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm using jquery [Wordsrotator](https://github.com/andreapace/wordsrotator). Everything is working fine, I want to add transition effect to the span if the word width increases/decreases.

Currently the width changes suddenly.

I have added transition but it doesn't seem to work

```
#myId
{
    transition: width 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear;
    -o-transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

Demo page [here](http://saurabhsharma.me/wordsrotator/)

Comment: the reason for this is because you can only transition animatedly between two numeric values. Width here is set to auto, so it won't animate.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/qepxyuL8/ I'm guessing you want something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the solution you were expecting, the issue here is that the width was set to auto (so not really changing) which meant we had to do one of 2 things **A)** update the width every tick and hope it stays in sync, **B)** change the Rotator plugin so it does it for us.

I went for the later. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/qepxyuL8/) so you can see it in action.

And now I'll say what I did. If you look below you will see 2 lines I have added

---

```
cont.width(cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordOut").width());
```

I added this line just after .wordsrotator_wordOut was first populated and what it does is set the width of the container (which that call cont) as the numeric width of .wordsrotator_wordOut

---

```
cont.animate({width: cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordIn").width()});
```

This line was put in just after we populate .wordsrotator_wordIn and it uses JQuery's animate library to animate the containers width changing from the width that is going out the the width that is going in. This line is ran every time the tick comes round.

---

This is the finished result with those two lines added. I suggest looking at the fiddle too as there are some other bits I did in there (just some css flex stuff).

```
/*
 * jQuery Words Rotator plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Andrea Pace
 * licensed under MIT license.
 *
 * https://github.com/andreapace/wordsrotator
 * http://andreapace.co.uk/wordsrotator
 *
 * Version: 0.9.0
 */

(function($) {
  $.fn.wordsrotator = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      autoLoop: true,
      randomize: false,
      stopOnHover: false,
      changeOnClick: false,
      words: null,
      animationIn: "flipInY",
      animationOut: "flipOutY",
      speed: 2000
    };
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    var listItem
    var array_bak = [];
    return this.each(function() {
      var el = $(this)
      var cont = $("#" + el.attr("id"));
      var array = [];
      if ((settings.words) || (settings.words instanceof Array)) {
        array = $.extend(true, [], settings.words);
        if (settings.randomize) array_bak = $.extend(true, [], array);
        listItem = 0
        if (settings.randomize) listItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
        cont.html(array[listItem]);
        var rotate = function() {
          cont.html("<span class='wordsrotator_wordOut'><span>" + array[listItem] + "</span></span>");
          cont.width(cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordOut").width());
          if (settings.randomize) {
            array.splice(listItem, 1);
            if (array.length == 0) array = $.extend(true, [], array_bak);
            listItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
          } else {
            if (array.length == listItem + 1) listItem = -1;
            listItem++;
          }
          $("<span class='wordsrotator_wordIn'>" + array[listItem] + "</span>").appendTo(cont);
          cont.wrapInner("<span class='wordsrotator_words' />");
          cont.animate({width: cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordIn").width()});
          cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordOut").addClass("animated " + settings.animationOut);
          cont.find(".wordsrotator_wordIn").addClass("animated " + settings.animationIn);
        };
        cont.on("click", function() {
          if (settings.changeOnClick) {
            rotate();
            return false;
          };
        });
        if (settings.autoLoop) {
          var t = setInterval(rotate, settings.speed);
          if (settings.stopOnHover) {
            cont.hover(function() {
              window.clearInterval(t)
            }, function() {
              t = setInterval(rotate, settings.speed);
            });
          };
        }
      };
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hey @Andrew, Thanks for the solution, meanwhile i discovered that 
`display:inline-flex` is causing issue on safari, while `display:inline-block` is working fine. But vice-versa is happening on chrome, with `display:inline-flex` working fine and `display:inline-block` causing issues.

Update pushed on demo: http://saurabhsharma.me/wordsrotator/
 issue comes up with the height